# Rotating a list to the right in scheme

Tags: scheme

if this is rotating a list to the left:

```
(define (rotate-left l)
  (if (null? l)
      '()
      (append (cdr l) (cons(car l) '()))))
```

How would I rotate a list to the right?

Comment: If rotating left moves the first element to the last position, then what would the opposite do? Where exactly are you having trouble when implementing `rotate-right`? You need to describe/include what you've tried (with hopefully some code) in addition to stating the problem you're trying to solve, so that the area where you've encountered trouble can be more clear. Is the problem retrieving the last element? Or is it building the final list once you have the last element?  Or something else ...?

Comment: (define (rotate-right l)
  (if (null? l)
      '()
      (append (cdr (cdr l)) (cons (car l) '()))))

Comment: I dont know how to move the last term to the fron

Comment: Examine the result of left-rotating the reverse of a list. There is symmetry here.

Comment: `(define (move-last-to-front last list-with-no-last) (cons last list-with-no-last))`. You can do it -- if you go by small enough, manageable steps. You knew about `cons`, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with writing a helper function to find the last element, it's pretty easy to do a recursive implementation:

```
(define rotate-right
  (lambda (lis full)
    (if (null? (cdr lis))
      (cons (car lis) (get-all-but-last full))
      (rotate-right (cdr lis) full))))

(define get-all-but-last
  (lambda (lis)
    (if (null? (cdr lis))
      '()
      (cons (car lis) (get-all-but-last (cdr lis))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short non-recursive solution:

```
(define (rotate-right l)
  (let ((rev (reverse l)))
    (cons (car rev) (reverse (cdr rev)))))
```

And here is a iterative solution:

```
(define (rotate-right l)
  (let iter ((remain l)
             (output '()))
    (if (null? (cdr remain))
        (cons (car remain) (reverse output))
        (iter (cdr remain) (cons (car remain) output)))))
```

---

```
(rotate-right '(1 2 3 4 5)) ;==> (5 1 2 3 4)
```